# Error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string, don't let me eliminate an item from my database in laravel 6.0

Tags: php, html, laravel, postgresql

***I tried to fix it but i couldnt, its for school***
***Queries without eloquent***

- Here i will show the code of my `destroy function()` ,my view ListEvent and also my query that shows how i can have the information from my database

***Index Function***

```sql
  $events = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT name_event, date
                                        from event 
                                        WHERE name_event is not null"

                                        ));
        return view('home.listaEventos',compact('events'));
```

***Destroy Function***

```sql
 public function destroy($id)
    {   
        $event=Event::findOrFail($id);
        $event->delete();
        return back()->with('deleted');
    }
```

***Code of my view eventlist that has the button delete the form give me the error that i said before***

```html
@foreach ($events as $item)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$item->name_event}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->date}}</td>

                <td>
                  <form action={{ route('events.destroy', ['event' => $item]) }} method="POST" class="d-inline">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" type="submit">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is getting the events.
You can use eloquent for the queries.

```
$events = Event::whereNotNull('name_event')->get();
return view('home.listaEventos',compact('events'));
```

Make sure to import the `Event` model with `use App\Event;` above the class name.

Also you need to pass the ID not the whole object.

```
<form action={{ route('events.destroy', $item->id) }} method="POST" class="d-inline">
```

Change the form element with the above code.

***UPDATE:***

Just use your current query and edit the your form like the above code.

Comment: The problem is that one instruction is that i cant use queries with eloquent, so i have to do it like sql queries

Comment: @Rinzler21 just stick with your current query and just update your form element with the code in my answer above.

Comment: it throws the following error now:`Undefined property: stdClass::$id`

Comment: Same error? Can you please call `dd($events)` before the `return view`

Comment: `Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined property: stdClass::$id (View: C:\Users\Anyelina\Desktop\ACAVUCAB_SGBD1\resources\views\home\listaEventos.blade.php)`

Comment: change `id` in `$item->id` to whatever is your primary key in the events table

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons:

```
<form action={{ route('events.destroy', ['event' => $item]) }} method="POST" class="d-inline">
```

1) You are adding an object to destroy while you define the parameter of method destroy() is $id, $id is an integer.

2) You do not get event_id in your query. Let pay attention if you write the query specify the field, or table does not have many fields you can "select *"